# How to draw and shade sets?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Suppose `$x$` and `$z$` are variables in interval `$[0,1]^2$`. How is it possible to draw the following sets and shade them?

```
$c1 \quad if 0<x<0.25,0<z<0.25$
$c2 \quad if 0.25<x<0.5,0.25<z<0.5$ 
$c3 \quad if 0.5<x<0.75,0.5<z<0.75$
$c4 \quad if 0.75<x<1,0.75<z<1$
```

Answer (score 5):

These are simple rectangles with lower left coordinates `(x_min,z_min)` and upper right coordinates `(x_max,z_max)`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=pi]
 \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,1.1) node[below left]{$z$} |- (1.1,0) node[below left]{$x$}; 
 \foreach \Color[count=\X] in {blue,red,orange,cyan}
 {\fill[\Color] (\X*0.25-0.25,\X*0.25-0.25) rectangle (\X*0.25,\X*0.25);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for the additional items in the comments: yes, you can easily add these.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
 \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,1.2) node[below left]{$z$} |- node[below left]{$0$}(1.2,0) node[below left]{$x$}; 
 \foreach \Color[count=\X] in {blue,red,orange,cyan}
 {\fill[\Color] (\X/4-1/4,\X/4-1/4) rectangle (\X/4,\X/4)
 node[midway,white]{$C_\X$};
 \draw (\X/4,0.05) -- ++ (0,-0.1)
    node[below]{$\pgfmathparse{\X/4}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult$}
    (0.05,\X/4) -- ++ (-0.1,0)
    node[left]{$\pgfmathparse{\X/4}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if you plan to draw several of such axes it can make sense to switch to `pgfplots`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can I know how it is possible to add labels $Ci$ inside each set and also the values in each axis? Also, what if I wanna draw the set $C5$ if $z=1$?

Comment: Can I know how you specify the coordinates of each rectangle? In this problem, each coordinate is a multiplicative of 0.25. What if I wanna first specify the coordinates of each rectangle first and then draw them? For example, (Xmin,Xmax)=(0.12,0.35), (Ymin,Ymax)=(0.45,.87).

Comment: @Katatonia You can then draw them separately, i.e. without loop. `\fill[<color>] (<xmin>,<zmin>) rectangle (<xmax>,<zmax>) node[midway,white]{<text>};`

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I have one more question. Can I know how it is possible to define a region like $0<x<1/14* sqrt(3)$ and $0<z<0.5(x+x^2)+0.5*sqrt(4x^3+x^4)$ and shade this region like the former cases? Is it possible to add labels as legend?

Comment: @Katatonia The answer is yes but this is in my opinion a new question. You can easily do that with `pgfplots`, which supports legends out of the box.

Comment: Should I ask a new question or modify it?

Comment: @Katatonia Please ask a new one. It is free of charge and less confusing for others.

Answer (score 3):

As follows from your question, you can draw your diagram by use of square shapes in the chain:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0pt,
  start chain = going above right,
     N/.style = {fill=#1, minimum size=10mm, outer sep=0pt, 
                 anchor=south west, on chain},
    tl/.style = {% tick label
                 font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt}
                        ]
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {teal,cyan,orange,red}
{
\node[N=\i] {$C_{\j}$};
% ticks
\pgfmathsetmacro{\k}{0.25*\j}
\draw   (\j,2pt) -- ++ (0,-4pt) node[tl, below] {\k};
\draw   (2pt,\j) -- ++ (-4pt,0) node[tl,  left] {\k};
}
% axis
\draw[Stealth-Stealth]  (0,4.8) node[below left]{$z$} |-
                        (4.8,0) node[below left]{$x$}
                                node[tl,pos=0.5, below left] {0};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: I hope these new 12 months bring you back that TikZ or PSTricks curve that I love so much: smiles and wonderful news and a lot of points ahahhaahah. Happy New Year!